# In Excel, how to scan for Duplicate in Column A. Place info in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my issue.  I have a WorkSheet Named Cost Data
In Column A which is named HEITEM
I have for example
7658798
7513807
789456
7513807

Note:7513807 is a duplicate

In Columns B - AG I have data needed for those in Column A that is a duplicate.

My question would be. How do I Scan the worksheet named Cost Data and move all instances of a duplicate in Column A to a new worksheet while showing all relevant data in Cells to the right?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add in a new column before column A (move all columns to the right) and in your new column put in cell `A2` (assuming you have a header row) the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,B2)
```

And drag it down fo rthe entire column.

You can then filter this new column A for all values not equal to 1 and then Copy / Paste it to your new workbook and remove duplicates (`Data` Ribbon > `Remove Duplicates`).

Of course there are countless other ways to do this, but this seems like a simple solution.

Hope this makes snese.